# Mysql Subquery as input second query

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate distance from mysql record, firstly I get all cordinates and saved as `LineString` object, but I have error. What is wrong with my sql?

```
WITH tmp AS
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ',lat,lng) SEPARATOR ', ')  FROM track WHERE vh_id='75' AND DATE(tdate)='2016-06-09' ORDER BY tdate)
SELECT ST_Length(ST_GeomFromText(tmp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, MySQL doesn't support the `WITH` clause; secondly, you should define variables like [10.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

You can change you sql to this;)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ',lat,lng) SEPARATOR ', ') INTO @tmp
FROM track
WHERE vh_id='75' AND DATE(tdate)='2016-06-09' ORDER BY tdate;
SELECT ST_Length(ST_GeomFromText(@tmp));
```

Or just with one query:

```
SELECT ST_Length(ST_GeomFromText(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ',lat,lng) SEPARATOR ', ')))
FROM track
WHERE vh_id='75' AND DATE(tdate)='2016-06-09' ORDER BY tdate;
```

Comment: Good, first option working, but mysql cut excedeec string, so ST_Length function not result anything.. any idea? howto set length temporary variable in mysql?

Comment: What do you mean? Did you want something like filling blank in left with a fixed length string?